# select tags running at server

Tags: asp.net, .net, drop-down-menu

Appoligise for what seems to me like a silly question, I'm not that familair with the web-based side of C# using ASP, and I've been unable to find a solution online - all the related things I have found have been for either `<ASP:>` controls or about adding items to the dropdown.

I am trying to return the string contains within the `<option></option>` tags, i.e. House, Reg, Year or Status. As I need to add the value to part of my Session variable in the code behind.

So I have added the `runat=server` parameter, and now I can access the select part via it's ID.

The count returns 1, but the item don't appear to be the string "house"... I can't seem to access the part I want, I thought I would be able to loop through items with findByText but it returns null.

Having a brain fart over this, could someone poke me back on track?

```
<div class="filterDropDowns" runat="server" id="filterDropDowns" name="filterDropDowns" visible="false">
                <select name="houseFilter" runat="server" id="houseFilter" class="row1 filterDropDown">
                      <option value="*" class="row1">House</option>
                </select>
                <select name="regFilter" runat="server" id="regFilter" class="row1 filterDropDown">
                      <option value="*" class="row1">Reg</option>
                </select>
                <select name="yearFilter" runat="server" id="yearFilter" class="row1 filterDropDown">
                      <option value="*" class="row1">Year</option>
                </select>
                <select name="statusFilter" runat="server" id="statusFilter" class="row1 filterDropDown">
                     <option value="*" class="row1">Status</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="filterButtonContainer" runat="server" id="filterButton" name="filterButton" visible="false">
                <input type="button" value="Filter" class="keyboardButtonStyle filterButton" onclick="javascript:DoFilter();" />
            </div> 

        <div>
```

Comment: Are you looking for a DropDownList: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dzka5sf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx or

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
regHouse.InnerText
```

or

```
regHouse.Items[regHouse.SelectedIndex].Text
```

I think this also should be

```
<select name="houseFilter" runat="server" id="houseFilter" class="row1 filterDropDown">
                  <option value="House" class="row1">House</option>
     ....
```